# React app, absolutely positioned child not positioned relative to its relatively positioned parent (in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a weird trouble in my React app. If I set a child's position to absolute and it's parent to relative.(Doesn't matter if using inline style or https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/)
Then in Firefox it will show it as it should by css standards - A child positioned left right etc. relative to its direct parent but in chrome (Version 70.0.3538.77 ) it shows the child positioned relative to the body of document.

```
const DataTableFooter = ({totalCount, page, size, onChangePage, onChangeRowsPerPage}) => {
      return (
        <TableFooter>
          <TableRow
            style={{
              position: 'relative',
            }}>
            <TablePagination
              style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                bottom: 0,
                right: 0,
              }}
            />
          </TableRow>
        </TableFooter>
      );
    };

    export default DataTableFooter;
```

Ironically plenty of the google searches about css absolute positioning errors I did came up with stories about how Firefox will not position the child relative to its parent in such situation and chrome does,(do I have an oppsoite day or hwat?) but with nothing useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have determined the problem. As is seen in the example code in my question I was dealing with tables and the react elements shown there will generate appropriate HTML **TABLE** elements. (Not divs styled as table etc but actual td tr etc.)
The table elements will not respond to position:relative in chrome as it is undefined in standard
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position

> ' The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group,
>   table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group,
>   table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined. '